# How to create a map from separate ascii files without merging them?

Tags: qgis, envi, ascii, esri-ascii-raster

I have three ascii files including longitudes, latitudes and pixel values. I just wonder whether there is anyway to display a map from the three files and save it in geotiff without merging them into a single file. I am using QGIS and ENVI-Idl.

Answer (score 2):

If your ascii format is one of the [GDAL supported ASCII formats](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html) you can build a *Virtual Raster Catalogue* (VRT) from it.

QGIS -> Raster -> Misc -> Build Virtual Raster

QGIS can treat these like any raster format so you can create a map with it and don't need to convert your ASCII files to another format.